# What makes Peavey amps so unique?

Tags: amplifiers

The more I listen to Peavey guitar amps the more I want one. To me there is just something magical about the gain structure of those amps especially the 5150 and all the models that succeeded it. Is there some design quirk of the amp that gives it such a unique and iconic gain tone? I cannot really describe it but I have not heard such a gain from any other amp.

Comment: I’ve read that they are often biased very “cold” in the power section. Personally I’ve never liked the Peavey sound and I like a really hot bias, so I’ve long assumed that’s the thing. One thing a colder bias would contribute to is crossover distortion in class A-B and class B designs.

Comment: True Anecdote: Back in the days people were keen to persuade me to use their products on stage I was accosted by a guy in a store to try out some huge monster of a bass amp. I said, "I've never been all that impressed with Peavey" but I took the bass he was proffering, slung it over my neck & played the first note… there was a colossal thump & an impressive shower of sparks flew out of the top of the amp. I handed back the bass, said, "Yeah, I'm still not that impressed" & walked off.

Comment: @tetsujin A book! A book!

Comment: @Todd Wilcox that sounds like an answer. Could you post it as such?

Comment: @Tom - honestly, these things are recalled to memory when prompted by something in this stack. I don't have a mental list of them all at the ready, to be able to structure them in a coherent way :)

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question and does not deserve a downvote.

Not only is Todd Wilcox right but there's a way to insert a pot so you can custom adjust the bias.

https://www.captainbob.de/publicuse/5150_bias_mod.pdf

Comment: Another true anecdote:  Back in the day I had a Peavey Bandit.  I spilled beer on top of it, spilled beer inside of it, knocked it down some stairs, and left it outside in below freezing temperatures.  It still worked fine and sounded the same.  Try doing that to a Fender amp.  A friend of mine was not so fortunate.  His started on fire during a song and it never worked again.

Comment: @ToastMan - I can't beat that, but I did once have a late 60's Marshall 50W top that took a long noisy tumble end over end down a long flight of stairs with no apparent injury at all.